# YII dependent dropdown is working fine on create but on update first dropdown data is coming but second dropdown data is not showing

Tags: yii

```
<div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ClassId'); ?>     
            <?php 
            $School=Yii::app()->session['Schoolid'];
            echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'ClassId',CHtml::listData(Classdetails::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"classid >0 and School_Id='$School' and Status=1","order"=>"classid")),'classid','classname'),
            array(
             'empty'=>'--Select a Class--',
             'ajax' => array(
             'type'=>'POST', //request type
             'url'=>CController::createUrl('Studentmarks/Dynamiccities'), //url to call.
             'data'=>array('Classid'=>'js: $(this).val()'),         
             'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'pid'),   
             )));
                 echo $form->error($model,'ClassId');
                echo $form->labelEx($model,'pid');
              echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'pid', array(),array('prompt'=>'-- Select a Student --')); 
             echo $form->error($model,'pid');
                ?>      
            </div>
```

Comment: Check for any errors and HTML returned from your controller to debug the issue.

Comment: Hey what is you meant that in update data is not coming. Ajax is working or not in update form or you want a selected pid according to selectet classid.

Comment: Please go through this below link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825161/dependent-dropdown-when-edit-in-yii

Answer (score 0):

As per the code specified, you are explicitly setting the second dropdown empty which is why it's not working in update view.

In update mode, you need to simply populate the dropdown with possible values with the saved value selected.

You can probably do something like this.

```
if($model->isNewRecord)
    echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'pid', array(),array('prompt'=>'-- Select a Student --')); // create
else
    echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'pid', $model->populateStudentsDate($model->ClassId));  // update
```

In `populateStudentsDate($model->ClassId)` method you need to filter and show the list of students as per class selection.